# Is there a way to capture each group if multiple occurrences are matched?

Tags: java, regex

I don't know how to explain the problem in plain English, so I help myself with regexp example. I have something similar to this (the example is pretty much simplified):

```
((\\d+) - (\\d+)\n)+
```

This pattern matches these lines at once:

```
123 - 23
32 - 321
3 - 0
99 - 55
```

The pattern contains 3 groups: the first one matches a line, the 2nd one matches first number in the line, and the 3rd one matches second number in the line.

Is there a possibility to get all those numbers? Matcher has only 3 groups. The first one returns `99 - 55`, the 2nd one - `99` and the 3rd one - `55`.

SSCCE:

```
class Test {
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d+) - (\\d+)\n)+");

    public static void parseInput(String input) {

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        if (matcher.matches()) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("------------");
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parseInput("123 - 23\n32 - 321\n3 - 0\n99 - 55\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

One more remark about the answer of Mike Caron: the program will not work if you simple replace "if" with "while" and use "find" instead of "match". You should also change the regular expression: the last group with the "+" should be removed, because you want to search for multiple occurrences of this pattern, and not for one occurrence of a (..)+ group.

For clarity, this is the final program that works:

```
class Test {
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) - (\\d+)\n");

    public static void parseInput(String input) {

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        while (matcher.find()) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("------------");
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parseInput("123 - 23\n32 - 321\n3 - 0\n99 - 55\n");
    }
}
```

It will give you three groups for each line, where the first group is the entire line and the two following groups each contain a number. This is a good tutorial that helped me to understand it better: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

Answer (score 6):

<strike>If</strike> I'm <strike>not</strike> mistaken <strike>(a distinct possibility), then every time you call `matcher.matches()`, it updates with the next match.</strike> So, basically, change the `if (matcher.matches())` into a `while (matcher.find())`, and you're ready to go.

EDIT: Actually, it's not `matches`, it's `find` that does this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29

Here's an example of using it:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html

Comment: Is it matcher.matches() or matcher.find() that will re-do each time you call it? (or both!)

Comment: I answered a question yesterday about `matches`, and recall reading it, so I'm fairly sure about that. `find`, I don't know, unfortunately.

Comment: I cannot make it work. Do you have any code which succeeded with this task?

Comment: Alas, I don't have a proper java development environment set up, so I can't test any code. However, it seems that josh.trow was correct. `find()` will match the next... match.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to match each line separately?

Remove the + to match only one line and change:

```
   if (matcher.matches()) {
```

to:

```
   while (matcher.matches()) {
```

and it will loop once for each match and automatically skip any unmatched text between the matches.

Note that matcher.group(0) returns the whole match. Actual groups start with 1.